# Intalling OpenSSL on EC2

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, openssl

I've been trying to install `openssl` on my `ec2` instance to access my webpages through `HTTPS`, but i cant seem to find a tutorial on how how to do it, i found this but it doesn't help much.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/InstallCert.html
I would like to know how to enable OpenSSL on my EC2 instance.

Thank you.

Comment: Which OS do you choose, Ubuntu? Windows?

Comment: so you want mod_ssl?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the Amazon Elastic Load Balancers (ELBs) to offload your SSL, you should search for a general guide for configuring SSL in apache on an ec2 instance:

[Enabling SSL on apache instance on EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948195/enabling-ssl-on-apache-instance-on-ec2)

Offloading SSL at the load balancers is a nice solution and makes it easier to scale your backend instances because you don't have to install the private key on all of the servers, just once, on the ELB.