# Configuration https on lamp web server ec2 aws with let's encrypt

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, https, lamp, lets-encrypt

I have a problem, yesterday i create certificate with let's encrypt on my ec2 instance. Now i want to use them o my site, but i don't know how i can proceed. Have you any suggestions?

I tried to do this but i hadn't any results:
https://www.paulwakeford.info/2015/11/24/letsencrypt/

than, after using webroot plugin on let's encrypt, i install mod_ssl.so on my istance, i edit my security group and enable https on port 443 and than i modify my httpd.conf right here:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/my-domain
    ServerName my-domain.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain/cert.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain/privkey.pem"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain/chain.pem"

 <Directory /var/www/my-domain>
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Have you any suggestions?

Comment: What happens when access your website using https ? Have you restarted apache ?

Comment: yes i tried to restart my service but i hadn't any results

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you pointed out uses SSL certificate to Cloudfront distribution, a CDN. Are your using Cloudfront? Because if you are using you need to set certificate on the distribution (and maybe to apache server too), otherwise on the apache server.

Try this look into:
[Enabling SSL on apache instance on EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948195/enabling-ssl-on-apache-instance-on-ec2)
and
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html

For the last, forget about "getting certificate" as you already have one issued by Lets Encrypt.

Comment: Another source: https://ananthakrishnanravi.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/configuring-ssl-and-https-for-your-website-amazon-ec2/

Comment: Let us know error messages if it fails so we can help better.